# normal approximation to a uniform distribution

Tags: calculus, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Earlier today I was talking to a machine learning researcher about how well a normal distribution could approximate a uniform distribution
over an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Although the following analysis involves nothing fancy, I think it's useful as it can be easily generalised to higher dimensions(i.e. multivariate uniform distributions).

I managed to make some progress and then I got stuck so I look forward to some constructive criticism.

1. I define the problem in terms of the KL-Divergence:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}_{KL}(P|Q) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) \ln \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx
\end{equation}

where $P$ is the target uniform distribution and $Q$ is the approximating Gaussian:

\begin{equation}
p(x)= \frac{1}{b-a} \mathbb{1}_{[b-a]} \implies p(x \notin [b-a]) = 0
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
q(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
\end{equation}

Now, given that $ \lim_{x \to 0} x\ln(x) = 0$ if we assume that $(a,b)$ is fixed our loss may be expressed in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$:

$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}(\mu,\sigma) & = -\int_{a}^b p(x) \ln \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx \\
& = \ln(b-a) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)-\frac{\frac{1}{3}(b^3-a^3)-\mu(b^2-a^2)+\mu^2(b-a)}{2\sigma^2(b-a)}  \end{split}
\end{equation} $

2. Minimising with respect to $\mu$ and $\sigma$:

We can easily show that the mean and variance of the Gaussian which minimises $\mathcal{L}(\mu,\sigma)$ correspond to the 
mean and variance of a uniform distribution over $[a,b]$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \mathcal{L}(\mu,\sigma) = \frac{(b+a)}{2\sigma^2} - \frac{2\mu}{2\sigma^2}= 0 \implies \mu = \frac{a+b}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \mathcal{L}(\mu,\sigma) = -\frac{1}{\sigma}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}(b^2+a^2+ab)-\frac{1}{4}(b+a)^2}{\sigma^3} =0 \implies \sigma^2 = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}
\end{equation}

3. What I find strange:

When I enter the optimal Gaussian parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ I obtain
a constant loss. To be precise I obtain:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}(\ln \big(\frac{\pi}{6}\big)+1) \approx -.17
\end{equation}

I find this really counter-intuitive yet I've gone through my calculations several times and haven't found any error. How can this constant loss be justified? Might there be a geometric way of explaining this result?

Intuitively, I expected that for small intervals(i.e. $b-a\approx 0$) the optimal loss should be much larger and for larger intervals the optimal loss should be close to zero.

Comment: As a quick comment you can be confident of the calculation of your optimal parameters - minimizing the KL-divergence this way round for a Gaussian is given by moment matching

Comment: @Nadiels I have gone through my calculation one more time and I can confirm that the result must be correct. I must say that I still find the result highly counter-intuitive however.

Comment: wait, shouldn't there be a negative sign outside of $(x-\mu)^2$, not sure if it changes anything but just wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commentor stated, your divergence results make sense in that if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{U}(a,b)$, then the optimally 'fit' Gaussian satisfies $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{V}[Y]$.
In other words, given a uniform distribution, the 'best' Gaussian is chosen by putting its mean in the middle of $a$ and $b$, and stretching $\sigma$ to match the variance of the uniform.

The fact that the loss is constant is interesting though. Note that each distribution has only two degrees of freedom (i.e. two parameters). My intuition is that it makes more sense to view it from the other perspective. Suppose we are given $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and fit $\mathcal{U}(a,b)$ to it. Note that the fit parameters are: $ a = \mu - \sqrt{3}\sigma $ and $ b = \mu +\sqrt{3}\sigma $.

Clearly, as $\mu$ changes, we are just shifting/translating around where the distribution is, so changing $\mu$ cannot affect our goodness of optimal fit. So that aspect makes sense.

Intuitively, as $\sigma$ increases, so too should $b-a$ increase to match it. However, in my mind, if $\sigma\rightarrow 0$, the $a\rightarrow b$, and both density functions should converge to being a Dirac delta distribution, not having a constant difference.

Note: computing $\mathcal{D}_\text{KL}(Q|P)$ gives rise to serious problems, though it seemed promising. (Perhaps if one could add small decaying tails to the uniform with some parameter or the like (i.e. to "soften" it), some insight could be gleaned.)

Comment: Everything appears to be correct except the part where sigma tends to 0. Doesn't the logarithm tend to negative infinity?

Comment: @AidanRocke Oops, sorry, thanks for catching that! I think it arises due to the differential entropy of the Dirac delta being negative infinity rather than zero.

Comment: One more thing. Is the KL-divergence well defined when the support of P isn't contained in the support of Q?

Comment: @AidanRocke Not really.... Depends if you consider divergent to be well-defined :3

Comment: I mean that the KL divergence calculation you have diverges in all cases, for any sigma. This is why I didn't calculate the loss this way. The bounds of integration in your case will be negative infinity to positive infinity.

Comment: @AidanRocke You're right, that's a mistake; there's a missing term there (i.e. the integration over the rest of the line)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74601/discussion-between-aidan-rocke-and-user3658307).